# gathering all available data for a year in "oec" library for R

Tags: r

I am trying to gather all available data on bilateral trade in a specific using "oec" library for R, but the function "getdata" will only return data for a specific country pair. I want to get all data on bilateral for a specific year (data on all country pairs). I tried writing a loop so I could get what I wanted, but it takes R too long to finish it. This is the code I used:

```
x = 1
y = 1
library(oec)
countries <- country_codes()

while(x < 264){
  if(x == y){
    y = y + 1
  }
  else{
    try(table<- rbind(getdata(countries[get("x"),1], countries[get("y"),1], year = 2014)))
    y = y + 1}
  if(y >= 264){
    a = a + 1
    x = x + 1
    y = 1
  }}
```

Comment: "OEC" stands for "Observatory of Economic Complexity"

Comment: Could you show a sample of the data with `dput` and what you expect as your result?. Maybe a different package or solution exists?

Comment: There are 263 countries listed, that's why I put 264